# How to use Instagram API to var_dump user data?

Tags: php, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I found this great resource here: https://github.com/galen/PHP-Instagram-API

Trying to use it to pull some data from Instagram and dump out the data, but I keep running into a problem:

```
Fatal error:
  Uncaught exception 'Instagram\Core\ApiException' with message 'Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter.' in /home/user/Instagram/Core/Proxy.php:553
Stack trace:
  #0 /home/user/Instagram/Core/Proxy.php(257): Instagram\Core\Proxy->apiCall('get', 'https://api.ins...')
  #1 /home/user/Instagram/Instagram.php(176): Instagram\Core\Proxy->getCurrentUser()
  #2 /home/user/public_html/igAnalytics.php(6): Instagram\Instagram->getCurrentUser()
  #3 {main} thrown in /home/user/Instagram/Core/Proxy.php on line 553
```

I guess the client secret isn't being mentioned or the access token isn't being read when I get to my final page.

Here's my layout, my `igTest.php` file:

```
<?php

    require_once( '_autoloader.php' );

    $auth_config = array(
    'client_id'         => 'myid',
    'client_secret'     => 'mysecret',
    'redirect_uri'      => 'http://example.com/igAnalytics.php',
    'scope'             => array( 'likes', 'comments', 'relationships' )
    );

    $auth = new Instagram\Auth( $auth_config );

    $auth->authorize();

    $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'] = $auth->getAccessToken( $_GET['code'] );

    $instagram = new Instagram\Instagram;
    $instagram->setAccessToken( $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'] );
    $current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();

?>
```

Which then redirects to my `igAnalytics.php` file

```
<?php

    require_once( '_autoloader.php' );

    $instagram = new Instagram\Instagram( $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'] );
    $current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();

    var_dump($current_user);

?>
```

My `_autoloader.php`:

```
<?php

    require( '_SplClassLoader.php' );

    $loader = new SplClassLoader( 'Instagram', '../' );
    $loader->register();

?>
```

Just to clarify what's going on, when I go to `igTest.php`, it redirects me to login to Instagram. When I login, it takes a second and gets me to that error page/message from above ^.

I believe that my `igAnalytics.php` file is wrong, but I don't understand how/what I'm missing there to make it work properly.

Comment: Just a consideration: is your `_autoloader.php` running `session_start();`?

Comment: @FirstOne I'll revise my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Check this out-

```
$instagram = new Instagram([
        'apiKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'apiSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'apiCallback' => 'CALLBACK URL'
    ]);
if (isset($_GET ['code']) && $_GET ['code'] != "") {
    $code = $_GET ['code'];
    $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
    $user = $data->user;
    var_dump($user);
} else {
    $loginUrl = $instagram->getLoginUrl();
    header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
}
```